# Defining a function by recursion over an inductive predicate in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to re-implement some Agda code of mine in Coq. My problem is that one of my Agda functions is defined by recursion on the structure of an inductive predicate.

In my Coq code, I'm trying to follow the same style but there's a pattern matching restriction that does not allow to analyse the structure of a value with type in Prop to produce a result in Set. My question is: Is there a way to define functions by recursion on proofs while producing results in Set (like sumbool)?

The code that contains all definitions to reproduce the error is at the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/e0e87eb8f0ed547ed5f4016a61f45dc9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need information wrapped up in the proof to construct your tree. Specifically, you need some split `(s1, s2)` such that `s1 ++ s2 = s /\ s1 <<- e1 /\ s2 <<- e2`. That split has to be defined computationally as opposed to extracting the appropriate split from the proof `H: s1 <<- e1 @ e2`.

The simplest way to fix this is to put `in_regex` in `Type`, to match how your Agda development works. This means that `in_regex` has to be constructed computationally, and as a result you can match on it freely.

`Inductive in_regex : string -> regex -> Type`

The use of `not` in `empty_in_regex_inv` breaks, but you can just write `s <<- #0 -> False`.

Credit to Ben Sherman for pointing this solution out!

It's also possible to keep `in_regex` in `Prop`, but then you need a separate computational way of matching regexes which will compute the split, and then a proof that relates this function to `in_regex`.